# Using HTML5 with older DOCTYPE declarations

Tags: html, doctype

If I make the doctype as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
```

Can the page also use HTML5 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#the-doctype) about the `DOCTYPE` indicates that

> Authors should not use obsolete permitted DOCTYPEs, as they are unnecessarily long

so while it does say you *can* use it, it also says you *shouldn't*.

That being said, in my experience modern browsers don't seem to care much about the doctype (even if you omit it).  You should still be able to use any HTML5 "features" with them including new semantic tags, new JS additions, etc., but just note that it is not advisable.

Comment: Thanks, the question came from an old wap page which need to upgrade to HTML5 page.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HTML5 specification, you can add some additional information into `DOCTYPE`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#the-doctype

> Optionally, a `DOCTYPE` legacy string or an obsolete permitted `DOCTYPE` string (defined below).